# Different size of the same text content when displayed on iPad versus PC

Tags: css, ipad

I have made a userinterface where you can create your own activity-cards with som text and images on. The problem is, that when the text-content is created and displayed on my PC it fits perfectly in the surrounding border-box. But when it is displayed on an iPad there is a text-overflow.

Link to an example: http://twww.dk/test_overflow.html
Example contain img with screenshoot from iPad so that it is easy to compare the different result of the same code on PC versus iPad.
Hope some one can tell me how to avoid any difference?
Thank you.

Comment: Add the code here as an snippet instead of making people view the raw code from the website

Comment: “I create the cards on a PC and want to set hyphens in the right spots, but that is impossible,” you wrote on your page. And that’s it. Impossible. Font size cannot be depended on. It can look different on different platforms, and even on different browsers on the same computer. Mac devices usually have thicker letter what makes them take more space.

Comment: The problem is solved now. But thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your "cards" you should have designed with CSS so that it acts like a container that resizes depending on the content size. That way you don't have that design problem. Otherwise you have to try to fit a dynamic content into a static container.

Comment: The problem is solved. I used tinymce editor for content editable areas. Thought I did convert all the units to relative but missed some.